Optimizing PySpark Code: Avoiding For Loop and Reduce While Maintaining Functionality
Update:
Added Input DF and expected output.
from pyspark.sql import Window, SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.functions import col, row_number, count
from pyspark.sql.types import StructType, StructField, IntegerType, StringType
import functools
from pyspark.sql import DataFrame

# Initialize Spark session
spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("RatingAnalysis").getOrCreate()

# Define schema
schema = StructType([
    StructField("UniqueID", IntegerType(), True),
    StructField("Agency", StringType(), True),
    StructField("NormRating", StringType(), True),
    StructField("NormRatingShort", StringType(), True),
    StructField("NormRatingLong", StringType(), True),
    StructField("RatingRank", IntegerType(), True),
    StructField("RatingRankShort", IntegerType(), True),
    StructField("RatingRankLong", IntegerType(), True),
    StructField("BLRank", IntegerType(), True),
    StructField("BLRankShort", IntegerType(), True),
    StructField("BLRankLong", IntegerType(), True),
    StructField("HighestRank", IntegerType(), True),
    StructField("HighestRankShort", IntegerType(), True),
    StructField("HighestRankLong", IntegerType(), True),
    StructField("LowestRank", IntegerType(), True),
    StructField("LowestRankShort", IntegerType(), True),
    StructField("LowestRankLong", IntegerType(), True),
    StructField("MidRank", IntegerType(), True),
    StructField("MidRankShort", IntegerType(), True),
    StructField("MidRankLong", IntegerType(), True),
    StructField("DistinctCount", IntegerType(), True),
    StructField("DistinctCountShort", IntegerType(), True),
    StructField("DistinctCountLong", IntegerType(), True),
    StructField("Count", IntegerType(), True),
    StructField("CountShort", IntegerType(), True),
    StructField("CountLong", IntegerType(), True),
    StructField("NRCount", IntegerType(), True),
    StructField("NRCountShort", IntegerType(), True),
    StructField("NRCountLong", IntegerType(), True),
    StructField("NonNRCount", IntegerType(), True),
    StructField("NonNRCountShort", IntegerType(), True),
    StructField("NonNRCountLong", IntegerType(), True),
    StructField("NonNRDistinctCount", IntegerType(), True),
    StructField("NonNRDistinctCountShort", IntegerType(), True),
    StructField("NonNRDistinctCountLong", IntegerType(), True)
])

# Create DataFrame from the updated data based on images
data = [
    (212015627, "MDY", "A", None, "A", 60, None, 60, 60, None, 60, 60, None, 60, 30, None, 30, 60, 250, 60, 3, 1, 3, 3, 1, 3, 1, 1, 1, 2, 0, 2, 2, 0, 2),
    (212015627, "S&P", "AA", None, "AA", 31, None, 31, 30, None, 30, 60, None, 60, 30, None, 30, 60, 250, 60, 3, 1, 3, 3, 1, 3, 1, 1, 1, 2, 0, 2, 2, 0, 2),
    (212015627, "FITCH", "NR", "NR", "NR", 252, 252, 252, 250, 250, 252, 60, None, 60, 30, None, 30, 60, 250, 60, 3, 1, 3, 3, 1, 3, 1, 1, 1, 2, 0, 2, 2, 0, 2)
]

ratings_df = spark.createDataFrame(data, schema)

def generate_ratings(window_df, count_rate, distinct_rate, rating_col, order_col, nr_flag, term):
    if nr_flag:
        filtered_df = window_df.where(
            (window_df[f"NRCount{term}"] > 0) & (window_df[f"NRCount{term}"] == window_df[f"Count{term}"])
        )
        window_spec = Window.partitionBy("UniqueID").orderBy(order_col)
        return (
            filtered_df.where(col(f"BLRank{term}") >= 250)
            .withColumn("row_num", row_number().over(window_spec))
            .where(col("row_num") == 1)
            .select(
                col("UniqueID"),
                col("Agency").alias(f"SourceAgency{term}"),
                col(f"BLRank{term}"),
                col(f"NormRating{term}").alias(f"FinalRating{term}")
            )
        )
    elif count_rate == 3 and distinct_rate == 2:
        window_spec = Window.partitionBy("UniqueID").orderBy(order_col)
        filtered_df = window_df.where(
            (col(f"NormRating{term}") != "NR") &
            (window_df[f"NonNRCount{term}"] == count_rate) &
            (window_df[f"NonNRDistinctCount{term}"] == distinct_rate)
        )
        filtered_counts = (
            filtered_df.groupBy("UniqueID", f"BLRank{term}")
            .agg(count("*").alias("total_count"))
            .where(col("total_count") == 2)
        )
        return (
            filtered_df.join(filtered_counts, on=["UniqueID", f"BLRank{term}"],
                         how="inner")
            .withColumn("row_num", row_number().over(window_spec))
            .where(col("row_num") == 1)
            .select(
                col("UniqueID"),
                col("Agency").alias(f"SourceAgency{term}"),
                col(f"BLRank{term}"),
                col(f"NormRating{term}").alias(f"FinalRating{term}")
            )
        )
    else:
        window_df = window_df.where(col(f"NormRating{term}") != "NR")
        filtered_df = window_df.where(
            (window_df[f"NonNRCount{term}"] == count_rate) &
            (window_df[f"NonNRDistinctCount{term}"] == distinct_rate)
        )
        window_spec = Window.partitionBy("UniqueID").orderBy(order_col)
        return (
            filtered_df.where((col(f"BLRank{term}") == col(rating_col)))
            .withColumn("row_num", row_number().over(window_spec))
            .where(col("row_num") == 1)
            .select(
                col("UniqueID"),
                col("Agency").alias(f"SourceAgency{term}"),
                col(f"BLRank{term}"),
                col(f"NormRating{term}").alias(f"FinalRating{term}")
            )
        )

def ratings_loop(df, term=""):
    window_params = [
        [0, 0, f"LowestRank{term}", col(f"RatingRank{term}").asc(), True],
        [3, 3, f"MidRank{term}", col(f"RatingRank{term}").asc(), False],
        [3, 1, f"LowestRank{term}", col(f"RatingRank{term}").asc(), False],
        [2, 2, f"HighestRank{term}", col(f"RatingRank{term}").desc(), False],
        [2, 1, f"LowestRank{term}", col(f"RatingRank{term}").asc(), False],
        [1, 1, f"LowestRank{term}", col(f"RatingRank{term}").asc(), False]
    ]

    df_reduced = df.select(
        "UniqueID", "Agency", f"NormRating{term}",
        f"RatingRank{term}", f"BLRank{term}", f"HighestRank{term}",
        f"MidRank{term}", f"DistinctCount{term}", f"Count{term}", f"NRCount{term}", f"NonNRCount{term}",
        f"NonNRDistinctCount{term}"
    )

    return functools.reduce(DataFrame.union,
                            [generate_ratings(df_reduced, *params, term) for params in window_params])

def join_final_df(df, df_short, df_long, on_column, select_list):
    return df.join(df_short, on=on_column, how='left') \
        .join(df_long, on=on_column, how='left') \
        .select(select_list)

print("Input df: ")
ratings_df.show()

final_ratings_df = ratings_loop(ratings_df)
final_ratings_df_short = ratings_loop(ratings_df, "Short")
final_ratings_df_long = ratings_loop(ratings_df, "Long")

final_ratings_df_joined = join_final_df(
    final_ratings_df,
    final_ratings_df_short,
    final_ratings_df_long,
    ["UniqueID"],
    [
        "UniqueID", "SourceAgency", "SourceAgencyShort",
        "SourceAgencyLong", "BLRank", "BLRankShort",
        "BLRankLong", "FinalRating", "FinalRatingShort", "FinalRatingLong"
    ]
)
print("final_ratings_df_joined: ")
final_ratings_df_joined.show()

I have a PySpark script that processes ratings data using window functions and aggregation. The code works fine but isn’t optimized as it uses a for loop and functools.reduce for combining DataFrames, which I believe can be improved. I am looking to optimize this script by avoiding the for loop and reduce while maintaining the same functionality.
I tried to combine the DataFrame transformations into a single operation using window functions and conditions within the same DataFrame. However, I couldn’t find a way to completely eliminate the loop and functools.reduce.
Expected output:


Don't expect people to understand what you are trying to do from your code. Post sample data and expected output or explain the logic in words

@gtomer - I've updated the question and added Input DF and expected output. Please have a loook.

By looking at your rating selector/calculator code the performance is looking good, specially because you are using some best practices like predicate push-down, filtering rows as early as possible and applying joins efficiently.
For loops are not essentially the villains in Spark if applied correctly. Obviously, avoid for loops with massive joins along with actions like count being triggered in a function, this for sure will lead towards performance degradation.
If it is under a good SLA I wouldn't improve performance unnecessarily. However, there are few suggestions for extra optimization.

Cache df_reduced or ratings_df given repeated union operation: If you aim to avoid fewer changes as possible in your current logic, a good alternative is simply caching df_reduced given the function generate_ratings is applied n times. Alternatively you can also cache ratings_df given it will be triggered 3 terms. Here's an example:

def ratings_loop(df, term=""):

window_params = [
    [0, 0, f"LowestRank{term}", col(f"RatingRank{term}").asc(), True],
    [3, 3, f"MidRank{term}", col(f"RatingRank{term}").asc(), False],
    [3, 1, f"LowestRank{term}", col(f"RatingRank{term}").asc(), False],
    [2, 2, f"HighestRank{term}", col(f"RatingRank{term}").desc(), False],
    [2, 1, f"LowestRank{term}", col(f"RatingRank{term}").asc(), False],
    [1, 1, f"LowestRank{term}", col(f"RatingRank{term}").asc(), False]
]

df_reduced = df.select(
    "UniqueID", "Agency", f"NormRating{term}",
    f"RatingRank{term}", f"BLRank{term}", f"HighestRank{term}",
    f"MidRank{term}", f"DistinctCount{term}", f"Count{term}", f"NRCount{term}", f"NonNRCount{term}",
    f"NonNRDistinctCount{term}"
).cache() # --> Add to the cache

df_reduced.take(1) # --> Simply triggers an action for forcing early caching

result_df = functools.reduce(DataFrame.union,
                              [generate_ratings(df_reduced, *params, term) for params in window_params])
    
df_reduced.unpersist() # --> Always unpersist to free up caching and avoid potential memory issues

return result_df


Ok but i still wanna avoid any loops and functools.reduce: Along side with caching (that will be beneficial anyways) and trying to avoid any refactoring in the core logic of generate_ratings, alternatively you can use DataFrame.transform and apply generate_ratings repeatedly. This strategy also prevents the for loops and use pure pyspark built-in functions protecting your for eventual performance degradation for the long run. This strategy may be also be applied to rating_loops in the beginning of your code

def ratings_loop(df, term=""):

    df_reduced = ratings_df.select(
        "UniqueID", "Agency", f"NormRating{term}",
        f"RatingRank{term}", f"BLRank{term}", f"HighestRank{term}",
        f"MidRank{term}", f"DistinctCount{term}", f"Count{term}", f"NRCount{term}", f"NonNRCount{term}",
        f"NonNRDistinctCount{term}"
    )

    df_reduced.cache() # --> Adds to the cache
    df_reduced.take(1) # --> Force triggering it before any transformation

    # Python NOTE: Avoid mutable objects (e.g. lists) in function parameters, use immutable (e.g. tuples) preferably
    item_0 = (0, 0, f"LowestRank{term}", col(f"RatingRank{term}").asc(), True)
    item_1 = (3, 3, f"MidRank{term}", col(f"RatingRank{term}").asc(), False)
    item_2 = (3, 1, f"LowestRank{term}", col(f"RatingRank{term}").asc(), False)
    item_3 = (2, 2, f"HighestRank{term}", col(f"RatingRank{term}").desc(), False)
    item_4 = (2, 1, f"LowestRank{term}", col(f"RatingRank{term}").asc(), False)
    item_5 = (1, 1, f"LowestRank{term}", col(f"RatingRank{term}").asc(), False)

    window_df0 = df_reduced.transform(generate_ratings, *item_0, term)
    window_df1 = df_reduced.transform(generate_ratings, *item_1, term)
    window_df2 = df_reduced.transform(generate_ratings, *item_2, term)
    window_df3 = df_reduced.transform(generate_ratings, *item_3, term)
    window_df4 = df_reduced.transform(generate_ratings, *item_4, term)
    window_df5 = df_reduced.transform(generate_ratings, *item_5, term)
    
    all_dfs = (window_df0.unionByName(window_df1)
                         .unionByName(window_df2)
                         .unionByName(window_df3)
                         .unionByName(window_df4)
                         .unionByName(window_df5)
    )

    result_df = all_dfs.dropDuplicates(["UniqueID"]) # --> Use pyspark.sql.Window to avoid shuffling
    result_df.display()
    df_reduced.unpersist() # --> Removes from cache


1 suggestion - i wouldn't unpersist until the final action. your current unpersist will remove the cache before your display() and your code then does not have a cached data to use for the action.

Thanks for the suggestion @samkart - I adapted a bit the answer
